# Shrink canvas but keep 'visible' screen proportions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, win2d

I'm making a paint-like program with a `Canvas` and several shapes (lines, rectangles etc that the user can draw) inside it. I want the user to be able to make this `Canvas` be scaled up and scaled down using pinch gestures to a large extent (within reasonable limits, say 5x times smaller/larger from the default size of `Width`=1000 and `Height`=1000).

This is pretty easily doable using a `ScaleTransform` from the control's `ManipulationDelta`. But I want the `Canvas` to be as the same size as before; meaning if the `Canvas` took up the whole screen and then the user pinches-inwards, the `Canvas` and it's contents should get smaller but the `Canvas` must still take up the whole screen space (so everything looks smaller but now there is more room for the user to draw shapes).

To do this, I tried increasing the `Width` and `Height` of the `Canvas` in accordance with the amount scaled.

```
private void ccDraw_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CanvasControl ccSender = (CanvasControl)sender;
        CompositeTransform ctSender = ccSender.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

        ctSender.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ctSender.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;

        ccDraw.Width *= 1/e.Delta.Scale; // sizing up inverse of amount scaled down
        ccDraw.Height *= 1/e.Delta.Scale;// same here
    }
```

You'd think this code would do the trick; I'm offset-ing the smaller scale size with an increase in proportions so the end result would be the same - but no the `Canvas` does shrink but there is no visible increase in `Width`/`Height`. However, I could see in the debug output that the Height/Width value had changed from default value 5000 to 6000.13~.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Or if there's a better way to go about doing this ? Note that the `Canvas` is not really the inbuilt one but the `CanvasControl` from Win2D though it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't working correctly?  I'd have expected that if you scaled the render transform up by some amount and then scaled the control down by the same amount you'd end up with something that's the same size on the screen.

Comment: Yes the control's `Width` and `Height` values do change but has no apparent difference in how the control looks like i.e. I can comment out the last two lines in the above code without having any visible difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think that modifying render transforms isn't really the right approach for this.

Instead, I'd recommend that you use the [GestureRecognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) class to process your input.

Keep the CanvasControl the same size, but adjust what you draw based on the GestureRecognizer's events.  The Transform property on the drawing session may help here with adjusting the scale of the items you draw in your control.

Comment: I guess that should work but I ended up using an offscreen render target like you'd mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32573648/3431319) and drawing the rendertarget in the drawing session.